# Unable to reference local variable with JsonBuilder

Tags: grails, groovy, jsonbuilder

I have the following code

```
    AddTicketCommand addTicketCommand = new AddTicketCommand(request.JSON)
    JsonBuilder jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
    jsonBuilder {
        ticket {
            subject addTicketCommand.subject
            requester {
                name currentUser?.name
                email currentUser?.emailAddress
            }
            comment {
                body addTicketCommand.comment
            }
            custom_fields {
                [
                        {
                            id 21857727
                            value addTicketCommand.zenRequestType
                        },
                        {
                            id 21854146
                            value addTicketCommand.zenProductId
                        }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

The addTicketCommand object is not null on line 2 but is undefined within the JsonBuilder closure.  Is it not possible to access local variables in groovy from within closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access `addTicketCommand` inside the closure as below. Mark the use of "parenthesis" instead of "curly" braces.

```
AddTicketCommand addTicketCommand = new AddTicketCommand(request.JSON)
JsonBuilder jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
    jsonBuilder {
        ticket {
            subject addTicketCommand.subject
            requester {
                name currentUser?.name
                email currentUser?.emailAddress
            }
            comment {
                body addTicketCommand.comment
            }
            custom_fields ([ //Note the use of parenthesis
                {
                    id 21857727
                    value addTicketCommand.zenRequestType
                },
                {
                    id 21854146
                    value addTicketCommand.zenProductId
                }
            ]) ////Note the use of parenthesis
        }
    }
```