# How to construct json using JsonBuilder with key having the name of a variable and value having its value?

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

How to construct json using JsonBuilder with key and value having same name?

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def userId = 12 // some user id obtained from else where.

def json = new JsonBuilder()
def root = json {
    userId userId
}
print json.toString()
```

Which produces the error

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.Integer) values: [12] Possible solutions: wait(), any(),
>   abs(), wait(long), wait(long, int), and(java.lang.Number)

Quoting the key does has no effect. Any idea how to make this work.

Edit:

I want the JSON to be like `{ userId: 12 }`. Also, why does writing the key as string not work?

```
long userId = 12   
def json = new JsonBuilder()
def root = json {
    "userId" userId
}
```

The example provided is just a snippet. The situation is that I have a lot of controller actions, which has various variables already. Now I am adding a part where I am trying to create a JSON string with various values the variables hold. So it's not very practical to change existing variable names and if I could construct the JSON string with the same name, it would be more consistent. Writing accessor methods for all the variables I wanted is also not an elegant method. What I did at present is to use different naming scheme like `user_id` for `userId` but again, it's not consistent with rest of the conventions I follow. So I am looking for an elegant approach and the reason why `JsonBuilder` behaves in this manner.

In case of JavaScript,

```
var a = 1
JSON.stringify({a: a})    // gives "{"a":1}"
```

which is the expected result.

Comment: When you say key and value to be same **name**, do you want `12:12` or `userId:12`?

Comment: I want it to be `userId: 12`.

Comment: Follow the first approach from my answer, in that case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- Declare accessors for the variable `userId`, if you need the JSON to look like `{userId:12}`

as

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def getUserId(){
    def userId = 12 // some user id obtained from else where.
}

def json = new JsonBuilder()
def root = json{
    userId userId
}
print json.toString()
```

- If you need the JSON to look like `{12:12}` which is the simplest case:

then

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def userId = 12 // some user id obtained from else where.

def json = new JsonBuilder()
def root = json{
    "$userId" userId
}
print json.toString()
```

- Just for the sake of the groovy script you can remove `def` from `userId` to get the first behavior. :)

as

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

userId = 12

def json = new JsonBuilder()
def root = json{
    userId userId
}
print json.toString()
```

**UPDATE**

Local variables can also be used as map keys (which is String by default) while building JSON.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def userId = 12 
def age = 20 //For example
def email = "abc@xyz.com"

def json = new JsonBuilder()
def root = json userId: userId, age: age, email: email

print json.toString() //{"userId":12,"age":20,"email":"abc@xyz.com"}
```

Comment: Writing accessor methods for say 10 variables each in 100 methods is not very practical. But I understand that it resolves the situation, so does having a different name for the key. Do you know why we need an accessor? Why does Groovy behave like this? Other languages like JavaScript behaves as intended. Isn't this a bug?

Comment: I do not think it is a bug. Use map representation instead. See my update. @kadaj

Comment: Yes I had found the solution independently. But, thanks for your effort. I will accept this as a right answer.

Comment: Thanks. In Jmeter 5.2.1, the code from your UPDATE section works for me in a JSR223 Sampler only if I replace this line 
def json = new JsonBuilder() 
with 
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

And this line:
print json.toString() 
With:
SampleResult.setResponseData(json.toString());

Maybe it helps someone.

Comment: do you know how I can append some other json object so that I make a more complex json structure?
example:

"emails":{
 "email":[
         {
            "email1": "test@test1.com",
            "isValid":true,
            },
   {
            "email2": "test@test2.com",
            "isValid":true,
            }
   ]
  }

Comment: @JustNatural This answer might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17538765/2051952

Comment: You can go to my SO user profile and search for JsonBuilder to find additional use cases.

Answer (score 4):

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def userId = "12" // some user id obtained from else where.
def json = new JsonBuilder([userId: userId])
print json.toString()
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get a desired output using a different param to `JsonBuilder`'s `call()` method. i.e., instead of passing in a closure, pass in a map.

Use `def call(Map m)` instead of `def call(Closure c)`.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

long userId = 12
long z = 12
def json = new JsonBuilder()

json userId: userId,
     abc: 1,
     z: z     
println json.toString()    //{"userId":12,"abc":1,"z":12}
```