# Strip out quotes from integer in JSON Builder

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I need to run the groovy scripts below to build a JSON template. The issue i am running into is that the integer in the template is surrounded in quotes. Stripping out the quotes from the variables treats it like a string.

```
cat port.txt
1001
```

Here is my JSON builder script

```
def test = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
   test {
    ports new File('ports.txt').readLines()*.trim().collect { p ->
        [name: "$p-tcp", protocol: "TCP", port: "$p", targetPort: "$p"]
    }
}
println test.toPrettyString()
```

When i run it, it spits out the following:

```
{
"ports": [
    {
        "name": "1001-tcp",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": "1001",
        "targetPort": "1001"
    }
]
}
```

However I want it to do strip out the quotes for the ports and targetPorts like so

```
{
"ports": [
    {
        "name": "1001-tcp",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 1001,
        "targetPort": 1001
    }
]
}
```

Any clue on how to accomplish this is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to construct json using JsonBuilder with key having the name of a variable and value having its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225600/how-to-construct-json-using-jsonbuilder-with-key-having-the-name-of-a-variable-a)

Comment: @NathanHughes Can you please advise how to do that? I am still a beginner with groovy.

Comment: Change `port: "$p"` to `port: Integer.parseInt(p)`

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the `ports.txt` file to always contain just integers, then you can convert the read lines to integers before collecting them. Without even trimming the strings. Also, note removed quotes around `p` in `port:` ant `targetPort:`

```
def test = new JsonBuilder()
test {
    ports new File('ports.txt').readLines()*.toInteger().collect { p ->
        [name: "$p-tcp", protocol: "TCP", port: p, targetPort: p]
    }
}
println test.toPrettyString()
```

Output:

```
{
    "ports": [
        {
            "name": "1001-tcp",
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": 1001,
            "targetPort": 1001
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. Exactly what i was looking for.